# How do you install cardano-wallet on an Ubuntu server and get the http API set up and running?

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

Here's an example:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/master/docker-compose.yml
NETWORK=testnet docker-compose up

Fantastic! The server is up-and-running, waiting for HTTP requests on localhost:8090/v2
```

No, it isn't. All that the above does is download a yml file.

I've also tried setting up a brand-new Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean, following the steps outlined here:

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet/

I've made sure to use the same git branches and tags that were listed, but running:

```
stack build --test --no-run-tests
```

takes a long time and then fails. I did figure out that `sudo apt install libsodium-dev` had been overlooked in the documentation, but I'm still stuck and haven't been able to find any solutions.

- EDIT: I went through the whole process again, without installing libsodium-dev and it worked, so I'm not sure why that was the case for me before.

I've destroyed the server and set up a new one from scratch each time, worrying that there might be something I've done that could affect each tutorial. I've probably downloaded and installed and tried compiling (with cabal and stack) eight times.

So. What I'm trying to do is set up on a brand new droplet, cardano-wallet with the REST API, so I can make requests and get responses. Do I need to install cardano-node first? Do I need to set up a relay vs a node like a stake pool? (I have a stake pool set up, but I had to hire someone to do that because I wanted to make sure all the security patches were set up correctly, and that I didn't do something bone-headed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to have a local running cardano-node so the cardano-wallet server has something to talk to/query. Once you have that set up, the easiest thing is to download the latest pre-compiled cardano-wallet binaries from [IOHK's github](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet).

Extract the cardano-wallet binaries and place them in your `bin` folder. You should be able to run `cardano-wallet -h` from the CLI and get a help prompt. Once that works, make sure CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH environment variable is set appropriately in your `~/.bashrc` folder. As long as cardano-node is up and running, you may now begin using cardano-wallet.

Follow the [cardano-wallet user guide](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/user-guide/cli) to begin. For a minimal setup, you can get started by running:

```
cardano-wallet serve \
  --mainnet \
  --node-socket CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH \
  --database <PATH_TO_WALLET_DB>
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you need further clarification!

Comment: But how do I get the http part working? I've asked on another question as well. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/how-do-i-get-the-http-endpoint-to-work-for-cardano-wallet

Answer (score 1):

To build cardano-wallet from sources you need first to have cardano-node, as stated here:

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet/

`This guide assumes you have installed cardano-node and cardano-cli into your system. If not you can refer to Installing cardano-node guide for instructions on how to do that.`

You should have at least 8GB RAM, what is necessary for running cardano node, from first look seems your build fails because of insufficient resources.

I have build by myself cardano-node with cardano-wallet exactly on Digital Ocean(Even on same OS - Ubuntu) using following documentation what I updated quite recently, so it does work:

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet/

If you still have a problem building cardano-node or wallet. Please put logs and I will try to sort it out.

For wallet you just need to have cardano-node binaries that it. You can use prebuild or build by yourself.

P.S.

And this do work:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/master/docker-compose.yml
NETWORK=testnet docker-compose up
```

Seems you just don't have docker and docker-compose installed. So if you see that command docker-compose is not found then on Ubuntu/debian you need to run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install docker-compose -y` and then it will work

Comment: I am reinstalling on a fresh droplet, following the installing-cardano-node instructions. I will post abbreviated logs if there are any problems. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to do it on an 8 GB instance, but I did have to log out and create a new session (and re-run the build both times).

Comment: Glad that you were able to build it. Cheers!